# Execute a Quartz Job with a Trigger from a Controller

Tags: grails, groovy, quartz-scheduler

I can run a cron from a static trigger from within the job folder and it will execute, but when I try to fire a trigger from my controller it just plain fails...What am I missing?

ERROR CODE: No signature of method: static com.example.TaskReminderJob.triggerNow() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[params:[name:Frank, email:frank@test.com]]]

**Quartz Job in grails-app/jobs/example**

```
  package com.example
  class TaskReminderJob {
     def reminderMailService 
     static triggers = { }

     def execute(context) {
         def email = context.mergedJobDataMap.get('email')
         def name = context.mergedJobDataMap.get('name')
         reminderMailService.remindMail1(name, email)  //send email via service       
     }
  }
```

**CONTROLLER CALLING THE JOB**

```
package example

class UserController {
    def quartzScheduler 
    ...
    //user is created
    ...                     
    TaskReminderJob.triggerNow([name:"frank",email:"frank@test.com"] )
}
```

Comment: Why would you need a controller in the first place? Series of events: User is created, some job should get triggered to send him a mail after 7 days of user creation, right? The quartz job should simply call a grails service **every day** to check if there is any user created 7 days ago from today, if yes, send a mail. :)

Comment: The way @dmahapatro suggested is the way I have implemented it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Correct your package path and then you can trigger your job manually using `triggerNow` method. And if you need to pass any parameter to it you can pass it like this:

**Controller**

```
package com.example

class UserController {
     def someAction(){
        ...
        TaskReminderJob.triggerNow([id:params.id])
     }
}
```

**Job**

```
package com.example

class TaskReminderJob {
    static triggers = {}

    def execute(context) {
        def id = context.mergedJobDataMap.get('id')
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this suppose to be a scheduled job or on demand job, if you want to have a scheduled job then you dont need to trigger it from your controller you can set the job to start on your application. For that define a trigger for your job using cron expression. Take a look at [this link](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-quartz/guide/scheduling.html) for how to schedule the cron job.

Comment: Yes I tried a clean build and refreshed dependencies. What else could have I missed?

Comment: I am not sure what you are doing wrong, but take a look at this example I created for you. [LINK](https://github.com/alidadasb/TestQuartzOnDemandJob)

Comment: @TylerRafferty btw I am using `1.0-RC9` version, check for that as well.