# Trigger Error when Triggering immediate Quartz Job with Grails

Tags: exception, grails, quartz-scheduler

I am setting up a system where users can request tasks be run asynchronously.

I am storing these tasks in a table in Grails Domain Class **ScheduledTask**.

I have two Quartz Jobs

- **CheckForScheduledTasksJob**

  - Triggered every 30 seconds
- **RunActionJob**

  - Triggered on demand when needed
  - (In the future there will be a configurable number of these running at a time.)

Currently the code flow is:

**CheckForScheduledTasksJob**

```
CheckForScheduledTasksJob {
    void execute() {
        taskService.checkForScheduledTasks()
    }
}
```

**TaskService**

```
void checkForScheduledTasks() {
    ScheduledTask scheduleTask = getNextPendingTask()

    if (scheduleTask) {
         Map params = [ scheduleTask:scheduleTask ]
         RunActionJob.triggerNow(params)
    }
}
```

At this point I get the following error:

```
| Error 2014-01-02 15:00:01,112 [quartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] ERROR core.ErrorLogger  - An error occurred while scanning for the next triggers to fire.
Message: Couldn't acquire next trigger: Couldn't retrieve trigger: com.mypath.RunActionJob
    Line | Method
->> 2848 | acquireNextTrigger        in org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   2759 | execute                   in org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$40
|   2757 | execute . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|   3787 | executeInNonManagedTXLock in org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport
|   2756 | acquireNextTriggers . . . in     ''
^    272 | run                       in org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread
Caused by JobPersistenceException: Couldn't retrieve trigger: com.mypath.RunActionJob
->> 1533 | retrieveTrigger           in org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   2808 | acquireNextTrigger        in     ''
|   2759 | execute . . . . . . . . . in org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$40
|   2757 | execute                   in     ''
|   3787 | executeInNonManagedTXLock in org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport
|   2756 | acquireNextTriggers       in     ''
^    272 | run . . . . . . . . . . . in org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread
```

The code for **RunActionJob** is still being developed.  All it looks like so far is:

```
class RunActionJob implements InterruptableJob, Serializable {
    boolean interrupted = false

    static triggers = {
    }

    void execute(JobExecutionContext context) {
        log.info ("HERE " + (new Date()))

        ScheduledTask task = context.getMergedJobDataMap()?.scheduleTask 

        return
    }

    void interrupt() {
        interrupted = true
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance for any help or responses.

Comment: I found that if I trigger the job as RunActionJob.triggerNow() with no params, that it works.  However that does not help me as I need to pass various arguments to the Job.

Comment: define an empty static trigger like : `static triggers = {}` in your job see if it helps. This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648836/execute-a-quartz-job-with-a-trigger-from-a-controller/18648940#18648940) might also help

Comment: will you please mention the code for class RunActionJob ?

Comment: @Alidad: I do have `static triggers = {}` in my job.  It does not make a difference with it or without it.  I had seen that other question before as was hoping that solution would work for me too, but it did not.

Comment: @Ak Goel: I added the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By trial and error I eventually found that the cause of this problem was passing the class ScheduledTask in the params.  I think that there were serialization errors with the class.

If instead I just passed ScheduledTask.id in the params, and then converted the id to the full object in the RunActionJob, then everything started working as expected.