# Quartz scheduler from finish to start delay

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler

I need to start a job 10 seconds after the last one finished. In other words, a finish to start delay.

Sometimes my job takes seconds to run. Other times it takes minutes. No matter how long it takes, I want the next one to run 10 seconds after that last one finished.

I am starting my job at the Bootstrap of my Grails 4 application using this:

```
System.setProperty("org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount","1");
LifecycleJob.schedule(10000l)
```

But this is a start to start delay. Using @DisallowConcurrentExecution and a threadPool with only 1 worker, I avoid collisions, but it is not what I want.

Tks!

Comment: Have you tried to setup a trigger every 10s? It won't start a seconf thread with @DisallowConcurrentExecution annotation however in the pessimistic case you will have to wait upto 19s for next run. If you need exactly 10s, you can trigger job dynamically right after you finished previous job with 10s delay.

Comment: I need exactly 10s. How to dynamically trigger after finishing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648836/execute-a-quartz-job-with-a-trigger-from-a-controller